# Custom polymorphic Newtonsoft JSON deserializer

Tags: .net, json.net

I have a recursive data structure. Something like...

```
Public Class Comparison
    Property Id As Integer
End Class

Public Class SimpleComparison
    Inherits Comparison
    Property Left As String
    Property Right As String
End Class

Public Class ComplexComparison
    Inherits Comparison
    Property Left As Comparison
    Property Right As Comparison
End Class
```

I need to deserialize to this from JSON.

As you can see, the only way to determine whether to use a `ComplexComparison` or a `SimpleComparison` is by determining if the `.Left` value is a string or an object. (NB They'll either both be string or both object)

So, I'm writing a custom converter and have got this far...

```
Public Class ComparisonConverter
    Inherits Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter
    ''<Snip>
Public Overrides Function ReadJson(reader As Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader, objectType As Type, existingValue As Object, serializer As Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer) As Object
    Dim obj As JObject = TryCast(serializer.Deserialize(Of JToken)(reader), JObject)
    If obj IsNot Nothing Then
            ''We''ve got something to work with
        Dim Id As Integer = obj("Id").ToObject(Of Integer)()

            ''Check if we''re instantiating a simple or a complex comparison
        If obj("Left").GetType.IsAssignableFrom(GetType(JValue)) Then
            ''LHS is a string - Simple...
            Return New SimpleComparison With {
                .Id = Id,
                .Left = obj("Left").ToObject(Of String)(),
                .Right = obj("Right").ToObject(Of String)()}
        Else
            Return New ComplexComparison With {
            .Id = Id,
            .Left = ???, '' <<Problem
            .Right = ???}'' <<Problem
        End If
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function
End Class
```

The branch of the `If` that results from the object being complex is where I get stuck. How can I re-invoke the deserializer on the `obj("Left")` and `obj("Right")` (which are of type `JToken`) ? Or should I Cast them to `JObject` and then factor this code out into a seperate function and recursively call that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be simpler than I expected and JSON.Net does all the heavy lifting for me...

```
Public Overrides Function ReadJson(reader As Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader, objectType As Type, existingValue As Object, serializer As Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer) As Object
    Dim Ret As Comparison
    Dim JComparison As JObject = JObject.Load(reader)
    If JComparison("Left").GetType.IsAssignableFrom(GetType(JValue)) Then
        Ret = New SimpleComparison
    Else
        Ret = New ComplexComparison
    End If
    serializer.Populate(JComparison.CreateReader(), Ret)
    Return Ret
End Function
```